# Uber eats type Horizontal ScrollSpy with scroll arrows

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What i am looking for is uber eats type menu style with auto horizontal scroll if the menu categories are more then the total width that is available and When the user scroll down, the menu active links keeps changing according to the current category that being viewed.
[image]

I am using material-ui at the moment and its `Appbar, Tabs and TabPanel` only allow a single category items to be displayed at the same time, not all, i have to click on each category to view that category items, unlike uber eats where you can just keep scrolling down and the top menu categories indicator keeps on reflecting the current position.
I searched a lot but i didn't find any solution to my problem or even remotely related one too.
Any help, suggestion or guide will be appreciated or if there is any guide of something related to this that i have missed, link to that will be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By following this Code Sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-xu80m?file=/index.js
and customizing it to my needs i did came up with my required scrolling effect by using MaterialUI.

The customized component code is:

```
import React from "react";
import throttle from "lodash/throttle";
import { makeStyles, withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import useStyles2 from "../styles/storeDetails";
import Tabs from "@material-ui/core/Tabs";
import Tab from "@material-ui/core/Tab";
import { Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import MenuCard from "./MenuCard";

const tabHeight = 69;
const StyledTabs = withStyles({
    root: {
        textAlign: "left !important",
    },
    indicator: {
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        backgroundColor: "transparent",
        "& > div": {
            maxWidth: 90,
            width: "100%",
            backgroundColor: "rgb(69, 190, 226)",
        },
    },
})((props) => <Tabs {...props} TabIndicatorProps={{ children: <div /> }} />);

const StyledTab = withStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        textTransform: "none",
        height: tabHeight,
        textAlign: "left !important",
        marginLeft: -30,
        marginRight: 10,
        fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightRegular,
        fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(15),
        [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
            fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(13),
            marginLeft: -10,
        },
        "&:focus": {
            opacity: 1,
        },
    },
}))((props) => <Tab disableRipple {...props} />);

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
    indicator: {
        padding: theme.spacing(1),
    },
    demo2: {
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        position: "sticky",
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        width: "100%",
    },
}));

const makeUnique = (hash, unique, i = 1) => {
    const uniqueHash = i === 1 ? hash : `${hash}-${i}`;

    if (!unique[uniqueHash]) {
        unique[uniqueHash] = true;
        return uniqueHash;
    }

    return makeUnique(hash, unique, i + 1);
};

const textToHash = (text, unique = {}) => {
    return makeUnique(
        encodeURI(
            text
                .toLowerCase()
                .replace(/=&gt;|&lt;| \/&gt;|<code>|<\/code>|&#39;/g, "")
                // eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-escape
                .replace(/[!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)=_\+\[\]{}`~;:'"\|,\.<>\/\?\s]+/g, "-")
                .replace(/-+/g, "-")
                .replace(/^-|-$/g, "")
        ),
        unique
    );
};
const noop = () => {};

function useThrottledOnScroll(callback, delay) {
    const throttledCallback = React.useMemo(
        () => (callback ? throttle(callback, delay) : noop),
        [callback, delay]
    );

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (throttledCallback === noop) return undefined;

        window.addEventListener("scroll", throttledCallback);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("scroll", throttledCallback);
            throttledCallback.cancel();
        };
    }, [throttledCallback]);
}

function ScrollSpyTabs(props) {
    const [activeState, setActiveState] = React.useState(null);
    const { tabsInScroll } = props;

    let itemsServer = tabsInScroll.map((tab) => {
        const hash = textToHash(tab.name);
        return {
            icon: tab.icon || "",
            text: tab.name,
            component: tab.products,
            hash: hash,
            node: document.getElementById(hash),
        };
    });

    const itemsClientRef = React.useRef([]);
    React.useEffect(() => {
        itemsClientRef.current = itemsServer;
    }, [itemsServer]);

    const clickedRef = React.useRef(false);
    const unsetClickedRef = React.useRef(null);
    const findActiveIndex = React.useCallback(() => {
        // set default if activeState is null
        if (activeState === null) setActiveState(itemsServer[0].hash);

        // Don't set the active index based on scroll if a link was just clicked
        if (clickedRef.current) return;

        let active;
        for (let i = itemsClientRef.current.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
            // No hash if we're near the top of the page
            if (document.documentElement.scrollTop < 0) {
                active = { hash: null };
                break;
            }

            const item = itemsClientRef.current[i];

            if (
                item.node &&
                item.node.offsetTop <
                    document.documentElement.scrollTop +
                        document.documentElement.clientHeight / 8 +
                        tabHeight
            ) {
                active = item;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (active && activeState !== active.hash) {
            setActiveState(active.hash);
        }
    }, [activeState, itemsServer]);

    // Corresponds to 10 frames at 60 Hz
    useThrottledOnScroll(itemsServer.length > 0 ? findActiveIndex : null, 166);

    const handleClick = (hash) => () => {
        // Used to disable findActiveIndex if the page scrolls due to a click
        clickedRef.current = true;
        unsetClickedRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
            clickedRef.current = false;
        }, 1000);

        if (activeState !== hash) {
            setActiveState(hash);

            if (window)
                window.scrollTo({
                    top:
                        document.getElementById(hash).getBoundingClientRect().top +
                        window.pageYOffset,
                    behavior: "smooth",
                });
        }
    };

    React.useEffect(
        () => () => {
            clearTimeout(unsetClickedRef.current);
        },
        []
    );

    const classes = useStyles();
    const classes2 = useStyles2();

    return (
        <>
            <nav className={classes2.rootCategories}>
                <StyledTabs
                    value={activeState ? activeState : itemsServer[0].hash}
                    variant="scrollable"
                    scrollButtons="on"
                >
                    {itemsServer.map((item2) => (
                        <StyledTab
                            key={item2.hash}
                            label={item2.text}
                            onClick={handleClick(item2.hash)}
                            value={item2.hash}
                        />
                    ))}
                </StyledTabs>
                <div className={classes.indicator} />
            </nav>

            <div className={classes2.root}>
                {itemsServer.map((item1, ind) => (
                    <>
                        <h3 style={{ marginTop: 30 }}>{item1.text}</h3>
                        <Grid
                            container
                            spacing={3}
                            id={item1.hash}
                            key={ind}
                            className={classes2.menuRoot}
                        >
                            {item1.component.map((product, index) => (
                                <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} key={index}>
                                    <MenuCard product={product} />
                                </Grid>
                            ))}
                        </Grid>
                    </>
                ))}
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default ScrollSpyTabs;
```

In `const { tabsInScroll } = props;` I am getting an array of categories objects, which themselves having an array of products inside them.
After my customization, this is the result:
[image]